# In what version of the Street Fighter series did Sagat first become playable?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, street-fighter-series

I remember the first Street Fighter, `Sagat` was a boss where he got his chest scar from Ryu's finishing **Shoryuken**.

But in which of the Street Fighter series did `Sagat` first become playable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sagat became the penultimate boss in **Street Fighter 2: The World Warriors**. Along with the another 3 bosses, he became playable in **Street Fighter 2: Champion Edition**.